# AttributeError at /pre_pred/

Tags: django, python-3.x, attributeerror

I've installed all the requirements and successful in running the local server but when I tried to run the prediction part of this [4th_umpire(The cricket match predictor using Random Forest algo](https://github.com/aasis21/4th_umpire) project I'm getting the following error:-

[image: This is the error part]

Here I'm presenting the error part of the code as mentioned in the error image.

```
def _transform(self, X, handle_unknown='error'):
    X_list, n_samples, n_features = self._check_X(X)

    X_int = np.zeros((n_samples, n_features), dtype=np.int)
    X_mask = np.ones((n_samples, n_features), dtype=np.bool)

    if n_features != len(self.categories_):
        raise ValueError(
            "The number of features in X is different to the number of "
            "features of the fitted data. The fitted data had {} features "
            "and the X has {} features."
            .format(len(self.categories_,), n_features)
        )
```

The exception line is **if n_features != len(self.categories_):** although I've checked that OneHotEncoder part and it seems ok to me.

Comment: I'm using python3.8 to run the project and haven't changed any part of the project except the front-end part and have built sklearn from the source separately as it was giving errors in general installation.

Comment: The [`OneHotEncoder` docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) say that the attribute `categories_` is available after fitting. Is the method `_transform()` being called before fitting is finalized?

Comment: I'm unable to verify that here, but I've changed nothing inside _encoders.py in _transform(). Should I present the complete code base of _encoders.py here?

Comment: I've checked the code and it seems alright here. Method  _transform() have been called after the finalization of _fit() method. Is that alright or I need to change something here?

Comment: If possible please check the code base at the project link I've provide and then help me here to run the project locally on my macOS mojave.